# Is making a function template specialization virtual legal?

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, specialization, c1001

In C++, a function template specialization is supposed to act exactly like a normal function. Does that mean that I can make one virtual?

For example:

```
struct A
{
    template <class T> void f();
    template <> virtual void f<int>() {}
};

struct B : A
{
    template <class T> void f();
    template <> virtual void f<int>() {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B b;
    A& a = b;
    a.f<int>();
}
```

[Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005) gives me the following error:

> fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

Comment: Nice error message! Maybe post it to MS Connect, even if your code is not "legal", the message should be better.

Comment: I don't know for sure, so I'm not posting this as a real answer, but I'd bet that it is not legal, since the vtable would end up being different in different compilation units that called the function with different types (or didn't call it at all).

Comment: gcc gives a plethora of error messages, starting with "testtemp.cpp:4: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope `struct A'"

Comment: it can't be legal, because you can't specialize within a class definition. and making the template virtual won't work either, because templates can't be virtual.

Comment: I filled a bug on MS Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=432999

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nice compiler error. For this type of checks I always fallback to the [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout) compiler before going back to the standard and checking.

> Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008
>   11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
>   Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.
>   All rights reserved. MODE:strict
>   errors C++ C++0x_extensions
>
> "ComeauTest.c", line 3: error:
>   "virtual" is not allowed in a function
>   template
>             declaration
>         template  virtual void f();
>                            ^
>
> "ComeauTest.c", line 10: error:
>   "virtual" is not allowed in a function
>   template
>             declaration
>         template  virtual void f();
>      ^

Now, as it has been posted by another user, the fact is that the standard does not allow you to define virtual templated methods. The rationale is that for all virtual methods, an entry must be reserved in the vtable. The problem is that template methods will only be defined when they have been instantiated (used). This means that the vtable would end up having a different number of elements in each compilation unit, depending on how many different calls to *f()* with different types happen. Then hell would be raised...

If what you want is a templated function on one of its arguments and one specific version being virtual (note the part of the argument) you can do it:

```
class Base
{
public:
   template <typename T> void f( T a ) {}
   virtual void f( int a ) { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   virtual void f( int a ) { std::cout << "derived" << std::endl; }
};
int main()
{
   Derived d;
   Base& b = d;
   b.f( 5 ); // The compiler will prefer the non-templated method and print "derived"
}
```

If you want this generalized for any type, then you are out of luck. Consider another type of delegation instead of polymorphism (aggregation + delegation could be a solution). More information on the problem at hand would help in determining a solution.

Comment: please note a call to b.f<int>(5); will generate a specialization that's not virtual and call it. Because you overloaded the template with a non-template, a call will prefer the non-template. but if you call b.f<int>(5); it will still call a non-virtual function.

Comment: that said, of course overloading is the way to go here. in fact, in the book "c++ coding standards", one rule is to avoid function template explicit specialization, because it's limited and overloading provides a superior alternative.

Comment: I'm trying to define a function GetValue that will return a value of type T. T is always from a known set of types. I want to be able to call the function from templates without having to give each version a different name.

Comment: My workaround now is to use a "out" parameter so that overload resolution can match it but I wanted to know if it was possible.

Comment: alexk7, an easy way is a type-to-type wrapper: virtual int getv(type_<int>); virtual bool getv(type_<bool>); while type_ is template<typename T> struct type_ { }; and call with b.getv(type_<T>()); now, overloading will figure out what to call, without templates, but with virtual :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I can still use the template in the base class to hide the use of type_: template <class T> T getv() { return getv(type_<T>()); }

Comment: Does anybody know if any update on this topic in C++20?

Answer (score 4):

According to http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/template.html ISO/IEC 14882:1998:

> -3- A member function template shall not be virtual.

Example:

```
template <class T> struct AA {
    template <class C> virtual void g(C);   //  Error
    virtual void f();                       //  OK
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, this is not legal code because a member function template cannot be declared `virtual`.

Yet even Visual Studio 2012 chokes on this:
[image: C++ internal compiler error on Visual Studio 2012]
[*Click here for full size*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeWg2.png)

Event logs indicate that the compiler crashed on `0xC0000005`, or `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.  It's funny how a certain (illegal) code construct can make the compiler segfault...